# Integer Overflow in VBA project

Tags: vba, overflow, excel

everyone.  Here is a small VBA (Excel) function that i wrote, full of MsgBoxes for debugging.

I am passing in the numbers 10 and 1 as arguments, and getting an overflow error when the program reaches the top of the For loop, before it begins the first iteration.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

```
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Function PerformanceTest(iterations As Integer, interval As Integer) As Double
    Dim st, tot, k As Double
    Dim n As Integer
    tot = 0#
    MsgBox "ok"
    k = iterations + tot
    MsgBox "ookk"
    n = 1
    MsgBox "assigned"
    For n = 1 To iterations
        MsgBox n
        st = Timer
        Application.Calculate
        tot = tot + (Timer - st)
        Sleep (1000 * interval)
    Next n
    'MsgBox (tot / k)
    PerformancTest = tot / k
End Function
```

Comment: Like others, I can't make "overflow" show up.  I agree with Tomalak that could point to a problem outside the function.  But if your code stalls at the point you say, then Tomalak's idea is hard to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redundancy removed, the essentially unchanged function runs without error in my Excel 2003

```
Function PerformanceTest(iterations As Integer, interval As Integer) As Double
  Dim st, tot As Double
  Dim n As Integer

  For n = 1 To iterations
    st = Timer
    Application.Calculate
    tot = tot + Timer - st
    ''# Sleep (1000 * interval)
  Next n

  PerformanceTest = tot / (iterations + tot)
End Function
```

So… the error you see is probably not within the function itself.

P.S.: Pro tip: ;-) Use `Debug.Print` instead of `MsgBox` for debug output.

Comment: @mcoolbeth: Can you let us know what the error was, ultimately?

Comment: General comments:

I always use Long rather than Integer because its faster.

Dim St, tot as double ' St has been dimmed as a Variant

for a set of accurate timers for the different flavours of Excel Calculation see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730921.aspx

Comment: @Charles: I've taken Integer because the OP did. You are absolutely right about the type of `st`.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of looking like a fool again, here's some input.

I would build my timer function like this.  It seems simpler to me.  (Not counting that I deleted some unessential lines -- I mean it's structurally simple.)

And if it ran without overflow, well that would be a nice plus.

```
Function PerformanceTest(iterations As Integer, interval As Integer) As Double

Dim st, tot, k As Double
Dim n As Integer

PerformanceTest = Timer
k = iterations + tot
n = 1

For n = 1 To iterations
    '' insert operation that takes time
    Sleep (1000 * interval)
Next n

PerformanceTest = Timer - PerformanceTest
PerformanceTest = PerformanceTest / k
End Function
```